# Transaction bundling in Corda

Tags: kotlin, corda

Trying to create transaction bundle to make use of single flow thread by creating  multiple transaction builders in same flow. We noticed that the flow class returns a single signedTransaction.

Is there a way where we can create multiple transaction builders in single flow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A flow can return whatever it wants. If you want a flow to create multiple transactions then the flow will return `List<SignedTransaction>>`.

Just remember that bundling the transactions into a single flow will not guarantee that they will happen atomically. If an error occurs between the first transaction and the second then the first will still be committed at the second will not. It depends on how you put your flow together. Some of these scenarios can be handled if your flow is put together carefully.

Comment: Do you think adding more txBuilder in single flow will give better performance or creating multiple separate treads ?